# How to create UUID's for a data frame created in Synapse notebook that wont ever repeat in a Azure SQL Database table?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, uuid

In a data pipeline I'm creating, I have to generate UUIDs for a PySpark data frame, this data frame will then be written to an Azure SQL Database table.

The code for the aforementioned is below:

```
try:
    results_final_df = spark.sql("""
                                  SELECT 
                                     uuid() AS ID,
                                     Email, 
                                     current_timestamp() AS DateCreated,
                                     Score,
                                     Product,
                                     Connection                                       
                                  FROM INTERM_VIEW
                                """)
    
    results_final_df.createOrReplaceTempView("FINAL_VIEW")

    display(results_final_df)

except Exception as e:
    logging_output = output_log(logging_output, str(e))
    mssparkutils.fs.append("/alogs/" + log_folder + "full_log.json", logging_output.to_json(orient='records'), True)
    raise e
```

I want to make sure that every time my code in the Synapse notebook generates UUIDs for the "FINAL_VIEW" dataframe (like in the code above) that those UUIDs **never** duplicate to the ones already in the database table, if duplicate UUIDs get generated in the notebook, when trying to write to the database table an error will be thrown because the column with UUIDs must be unique.

To prevent this, I first create a data frame called "dupe_test_DF" that will join the UUIDs created in the notebook to the UUIDs already in the database.

If there is a match, it means the UUIDs created in the notebook already exist in the database and that my "FINAL_VIEW" data frame needs to keep creating new UUIDs until it no longer has a match to the UUIDs already in the database.

```
""" Use the below to test for Duplicate UUIDs. """

try:
    dupe_test_DF = spark.sql("""
                                SELECT
                                    UPPER(PT.ID) AS ID_Notebook,
                                    UPPER(ST.ID) AS ID_Database
                                FROM FINAL_VIEW AS PT
                                INNER JOIN DATABASE_TABLE AS ST
                                ON UPPER(PT.ID) = UPPER(ST.ID)
                             """)
                                
    display(dupe_test_DF)   
    
except Exception as e:
    logging_output = output_log(logging_output, str(e))
    mssparkutils.fs.append("/alogs/" + log_folder + "full_log.json", logging_output.to_json(orient='records'), True)
    raise e
```

If the above test data frame has more than 0 rows then I have duplicate UUIDs between my notebook environment and database table I intend to write to.

So, I wrote the below code to keep generating new UUIDs for the "FINAL_VIEW" data frame until there are no more UUID matches between my two environments:

```
""" Keep generating new UUIDs until no more duplicate UUID matches are found between the notebook data frame and the database table."""

try:
    if dupe_test_DF.count() > 0:
    
        print("Duplicate UUIDs found, new UUIDs will be generated to prevent duplicates.")
        
        while dupe_test_DF.count() > 0:
            
            results_final_df = spark.sql("""
                                           SELECT 
                                              uuid() AS ID,
                                              Email, 
                                              current_timestamp() AS DateCreated,
                                              Score, 
                                              Product,
                                              Connection                                       
                                            FROM INTERM_VIEW
                                         """)
            results_final_df.createOrReplaceTempView("FINAL_VIEW")
                                    
            dupe_test_DF = spark.sql("""
                                        SELECT
                                            UPPER(PT.ID) AS ID_Notebook,
                                            UPPER(ST.ID) AS ID_Database
                                        FROM FINAL_VIEW AS PT
                                        INNER JOIN DATABASE_TABLE AS ST
                                        ON UPPER(PT.ID) = UPPER(ST.ID)
                                    """)
    else:
        print("No Duplicate UUIDs in DATABASE_TABLE table found.")

except Exception as e:
    logging_output = output_log(logging_output, str(e))
    mssparkutils.fs.append("/alogs/" + log_folder + "full_log.json", logging_output.to_json(orient='records'), True)
    raise e
```

The above code works and prevents duplicate UUIDs between the two environments, but I wanted to know how can I create UUIDs for my data frame that will NEVER repeat the UUIDs in the database table so that this check wont even be necessary?

It's very possible that in the future I may have to create UUIDs for other data frames, which may mean repeating this code, this is something I want to avoid.

I may have a good solution (I hope) but I'm looking for the best way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not received any answers after 6 months so I will post my own solution I stated in the question as a good way to do this.

First create a data frame called "dupe_test_DF" that will join the UUIDs created in the notebook to the UUIDs already in the database.

If there is a match, it means the UUIDs created in the notebook already exist in the database and that my "FINAL_VIEW" data frame needs to keep creating new UUIDs until it no longer has a match to the UUIDs already in the database.

```
""" Use the below to test for Duplicate UUIDs. """

try:
    dupe_test_DF = spark.sql("""
                                SELECT
                                    UPPER(PT.ID) AS ID_Notebook,
                                    UPPER(ST.ID) AS ID_Database
                                FROM FINAL_VIEW AS PT
                                INNER JOIN DATABASE_TABLE AS ST
                                ON UPPER(PT.ID) = UPPER(ST.ID)
                             """)
                                
    display(dupe_test_DF)   
    
except Exception as e:
    logging_output = output_log(logging_output, str(e))
    mssparkutils.fs.append("/alogs/" + log_folder + "full_log.json", logging_output.to_json(orient='records'), True)
    raise e
```

If the above test data frame has more than 0 rows then I have duplicate UUIDs between my notebook environment and database table I intend to write to.

So, I wrote the below code to keep generating new UUIDs for the "FINAL_VIEW" data frame until there are no more UUID matches between my two environments:

```
""" Keep generating new UUIDs until no more duplicate UUID matches are found between the notebook data frame and the database table."""

try:
    if dupe_test_DF.count() > 0:
    
        print("Duplicate UUIDs found, new UUIDs will be generated to prevent duplicates.")
        
        while dupe_test_DF.count() > 0:
            
            results_final_df = spark.sql("""
                                           SELECT 
                                              uuid() AS ID,
                                              Email, 
                                              current_timestamp() AS DateCreated,
                                              Score, 
                                              Product,
                                              Connection                                       
                                            FROM INTERM_VIEW
                                         """)
            results_final_df.createOrReplaceTempView("FINAL_VIEW")
                                    
            dupe_test_DF = spark.sql("""
                                        SELECT
                                            UPPER(PT.ID) AS ID_Notebook,
                                            UPPER(ST.ID) AS ID_Database
                                        FROM FINAL_VIEW AS PT
                                        INNER JOIN DATABASE_TABLE AS ST
                                        ON UPPER(PT.ID) = UPPER(ST.ID)
                                    """)
    else:
        print("No Duplicate UUIDs in DATABASE_TABLE table found.")

except Exception as e:
    logging_output = output_log(logging_output, str(e))
    mssparkutils.fs.append("/alogs/" + log_folder + "full_log.json", logging_output.to_json(orient='records'), True)
    raise e
```

The above code works and prevents duplicate UUIDs between the two environments. Once the "dupe_test_DF" dataframe no longer has a count greater than 0 (meaning duplicate UUID's were found between the notebook table and the Azure SQL Database table we are about to write to) it will break out of the while loop and the code which writes to the table in Azure SQL Database will run; I did not include that code here.